# Vector field determining a family of codimension 1 submanifolds perpendicular to the field

Tags: analysis, manifolds, differential-topology

Given a smooth vector field in a compact domain contained in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, under what conditions can we conclude that this determines uniquely a family of $(n-1)$-dimensional smooth submanifolds so that at each point on each submanifold, the unit normal is in the direction of the vector field value at that point?

Comment: Do you know the Frobenius Theorem?

Comment: The specific context in which I am interested in this is to consider pde's with a standard elliptic matrix with smooth ($C^{r}$ would be even better) elliptic coefficients and wanting to know if in a compact domain not containing the origin, the field of vectors (which need not be unit vectors any more) in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ obtained by pointwise application of the elliptic matrix on the unit radial vectors can give me a foliation by $(n-1)$-dimensional manifolds.

Comment: I know the Frobenius theorem talks about subbundles of the tangent bundle and if those are involutive in terms of the Lie bracket, then there is a regular foliation. In this case, I am hoping to work with the normal bundle, and I am not able to see an immediate connection.

Answer (score 4):

Turn the vector field $V$ into a $1$-form $\omega$ in the obvious way. Then you will get integrability iff $d\omega\wedge\omega=0$.

(In the case $n=3$ you could state this directly as $\text{curl}\,V\times V=0$.)

Comment: And for (some of) the intermediate calculations for why the Frobenius condition gives the condition on the curl, OP can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4504691/568204).

Comment: Yes, this is very helpful, thank you!

Comment: @AritroPathak . Yes it is. Again MSE helped to prevent that a famous theorem got buried in Bourbakist literature.